# NSEntityDescription.entityForName returns a nil object even though everything is spelt correctly

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am trying to save some data using coredata in Swift. This is how I have declared a managedObjectContext in my view controller (named ParallaxViewController).

```
  let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate
      as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
```

I have created an xcdatamodeld named `History.xcdatamodeld`, with an entity called `Previous` in it, as seen here:[image]
I have created an NSManagedObject subclass (using the editor menu) to make a class called `Previous`, and then I changed the name of the Class field of the `Previous` entity to `NameOfApp.Previous`. I was under the impression that this was all I needed to do to set up coredata access properly.

So, using my managedObjectContext that I created in ParallaxViewController, I tried to access it with this:

```
let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Previous", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)

let contact = Previous(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
```

But for some reason I get a `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` error. In the debugger the value of entityDescription is `nil`. I'm certain that everything is spelt correctly which is apparently the biggest cause of issues like this.

Comment: Is the AppDelegate using the `History` model when it builds the CoreData stack?

Comment: @pbasdf I'm unsure how to check this. I have ticked the "Use Core Data" on the create new project screen if that's what you mean

Comment: If you look in the AppDelegate.swift, you will find a number of functions and var definitions that build the CoreData "stack" - a series of objects that underpin CoreData (including the managedObjectContext).  One of those objects is the ManagedObjectModel.  That is created by reading a file which Xcode builds from your xcdatamodel.  But Apple's standard templates assume the model will have the same name as the app (with extension "momd").  Look for the `lazy var managedObjectModel` definition - either change the name of your xcdatamodel file to match, or vice versa.

Comment: @pbasdf i am using xcode 7 beta and i don't see .momd but is .xcdatamodeld the xcode 7 equivalent?

Comment: @alex The .xcdatamodeld in your project is compiled to produce the .momd.  So if you have `myproject.xcdatamodeld` it will be compiled into `myproject.momd`.